# Update Date anomoly

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

As I was adding some functionality to a form, it required that I update a date for a row. My update query was built out to be:

```
   "update tblReview set tblreview.[reviewDate] = me.currdate WHERE empID = '"& me.empid & "';"
```

(basically)
it was printed out to be

```
  "Update tblReview set tblreview.[reviewdate] = 7/24/2012 WHERE empID = '1';"
```

Cool, that's what I wanted. Now lets look at my data

```
 *empId*       *reviewDate*
    1             12/30/1899
```

What?! Why does it do this? Okay, sure, I should probably put '#' characters around my date to fix it. But why does it update to this ridiculous value rather than giving me some sort of error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be:

```
"update tblReview set tblreview.[reviewDate] =#" _
& Format( me.currdate,"yyyy/mm/dd") _
& "# WHERE empID = " & me.empid
```

Answer (score 1):

You tried setting it to 7 divided by 24 divided by 2012 days.

You need:

```
"update tblReview set tblreview.[reviewDate] = '" & _
    Format(me.currdate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' WHERE empID = " & me.empid & " ;"
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I know that it was an issue with the formatting, I was just wondering where that crazy date came from! Interesting stuff, thanks.

Comment: I doubt that empid is a text field.

Comment: It is in this case -  It needs the single quotes. But, I wasn't particularly concerns with the specifics of the implementation, I was just providing an example and wondering where this date value came from. I thought I just needed '#' characters around it - Thanks to all of you for the heads up on the format() function

Comment: So Bobby, you were right...(accidentally) on the empID part ;)

Comment: @Scotch - you'd be surprised how often that happens :)